# Can't export and use the trait Deserialize from serde

Tags: json, rust

I'm using the crate `serde_json`. Here's my TOML file:

```
[dependencies]
hyper = "0.6.8"
time = "0.1"
serde_json = "0.5.1"
serde = "0.5.1"
```

And export:

```
extern crate serde;

// use serde::de::Deserialize; // unresolved import
use serde::Deserialize;  // unresolved import
```

In the documentation it says it's in the module `serde::de`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Let's read the error message you posted in your comment:

```
error: unresolved import serde::de::Deserialize. Did you mean self::serde::de?
src/file1.rs:7 use serde::de::Deserialize;
```

There's a very important bit there: `src/file1.rs`. I bet this means that you're in a submodule, rather than in the crate root. You'll want

```
use ::serde::de::Deserialize;
```

Note the `::` at the front. This makes it look from the crate root.

Comment: I don't know, I get this `error: unresolved import serde::de::Deserialize. Did you mean self::serde::de`?
`src/file1.rs:7 use serde::de::Deserialize;`
`

Comment: Ah ha! I know what's wrong. Let me update my answer.

Comment: `which means it's looking for a serde in this module` - for some reason other modules in the same file (file1.rs) get exported correctly. anyway, it's working now.

Comment: "use is relative by default" I was under impression that `use` is always absolute, and you need to use `self` in order to import something from this module and below, like `use self::SomeEnum::*` to get all variants from an enum or `use self::submodule:subsubmodule` to import one of the child submodules.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev hmm, that would seem to be true, but then why isn't it not going from the crate root here? We would only need one of `::` and `self` if it were always one or the other.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik, I guess the reason could be that `extern crate` declaration is located in a submodule, not in a crate root. But that's only a guessing, of course; a full example of a non-compiling crate would be nice to have.

Answer (score 14):

In `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
```